# EKS - Use IAM roles for service accounts on multiple clusters

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam, amazon-eks

I am trying to use IAM roles for service accounts in EKS.
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/iam-roles-for-service-accounts.html

When it comes to create the IAM role to be assigned to a service account, I have to create it with a trust policy that refers to the OIDC provider of a specific cluster.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/create-service-account-iam-policy-and-role.html

Specifically:

`You must also create an IAM role for your Kubernetes service accounts to use before you associate it with a service account. The trust relationship is scoped to your cluster and service account so that each cluster and service account combination requires its own role`

This part: `The trust relationship is scoped to your cluster and service account` is REALLY limiting.

My issue with this is that I would like clusters to be ephemeral and short lived, but I don't want to touch up the trust policy of all the application IAM roles assigned to Service accounts in the cluster every time I rebuild a cluster. Furthermore, I would like the same kubernetes manifest manifest (for the same service account) to be applied, identical, to more than one cluster, potentially on clusters that didn't exist when the manifest was written and the application IAM role was created.

In pre-eks time, when using `kube2iam`, I was simply creating cluster nodes that shared the instance-profile, and use the role of the instance profile in the trust policy of the IAM roles assigned to pods. That allowed me to write manifests that would work on more than one cluster.

I cannot, apparently, share an OIDC provider between two EKS clusters, in a similar way as I was sharing the node role (instance-profile) before.

Am I approaching the problem from the wrong end? I don't want to hardcode in the trust policy of the application IAM roles something (in this case the OIDC provider) that is cluster specific, because the cluster should not be eternal. I want to be able to rebuild it from scratch without rebuilding the roles of the applications (or the service account manifests) that I might run on it.

I would stick to kube2iam, but that doesn't work with fargate profiles, so IAM roles for service accounts is my only solution.

Comment: For the record, I ended up adding the OIDC provider of each new cluster I create ti the trust policy of the roles. I manage the clusters and the roles from the same terraform project, so in the end it wasn't *that* bad.
I don't consider this an answer, as I ended up doing what I wanted to avoid.